Jenkins - How to trigger a replay build from API with custom pipeline
I have a Jenkins job with a pipeline retrieved from a Git repository. I am currently developing it and I find very annoying to copy and paste from VSCode to the replay on Jenkins every time I want to rerun it.

Is there a method to replay a build from the Jenkins API?
Note I've already triggered a build on a job via curl, with the following command:
curl -X POST ${JENKINS_URL_AUTH}/job/test-job/go-compilations/test-multirepo/develop/build

But I don't seem to find the method for replaying builds, I guess it ideally will be something like:
curl -X POST -F "k8sagent=<k8sagent.groovy" -F "main-script=<Jenkinsfile" "$JENKINS_URL_AUTH/job/test-job/go-compilations/test-multirepo/develop/build/127/replay"

